# How can I share files from Firestore via URL in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am attempting to share a PDF from Firestore using a URL in my SwiftUI app. However, when I tap the share button, two error messages appear in the debug console:

1- This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.

2- Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}

```
struct PresentPDF: View {
    
    let data: Data
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            if let url = URL(string: data.pdfUrl ?? "" ) {
                PDFKitView(url: url)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup {
                Button(action: sharePDF) {
                    Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
            }
                          
            
        }
    }
    
    func sharePDF() {
        let url = (URL(string: data.pdfUrl ?? "")!)
        
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url)
        
        let data = pdfDocument?.dataRepresentation()!
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [data as Any], applicationActivities: nil)
        
        if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.isKind(of: UIWindowScene.self) }) as? UIWindowScene {
            if let topViewController = windowScene.windows.first?.rootViewController {
                topViewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix that issue?

I hope somebody can suggest a function that is better than the one I have implemented.

Comment: What are `Data` and `PDFKitView`? Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Fetch pdf url from firestore. no issue with fetching url, my issue with share pdf file